# Recently installed Ubuntu, having issues with multiple display setup

Tags: boot, nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have an Asus Zenbook UX32VD dual booting Windows 8 and Ubuntu 16.04 (installed last week) and I also have two external monitors hooked up to it via the HDMI and mini VGA ports.

When I boot up and if anything is connected to the HDMI or VGA ports then my laptop screen gets disabled and only the display that is turned on works, note that I can't see the GRUB boot options but on booting Ubuntu I can see the background image. After booting into Ubuntu I can't see the prompt to login as, presumably, it's on the disabled laptop display.  I can't for the life of me figure out how to keep the laptop display enabled.

If I disconnect the HDMI/VGA and allow it to boot then I can see GRUB options on the laptop display and after booting into Ubuntu, also the login prompt. I can then login and plug in the other monitors to have them work.

Everything was working OK up until today where.. the VGA display doesn't work at all unless the HDMI is also plugged in. If I unplug the HDMI but leave the VGA plugged in then the VGA display has no image. If I check the System Settings -> Displays .. it seems to detect the VGA display but I'm unable to use it.

I tested against Windows 8 and it all works as expected, that is, regardless of which HDMI/VGA is plugged in... the laptop screen and the plugged in external display all function as expected.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

So, personally I don't own this laptop, however I spent some time looking around. What I found was this:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AsusZenbook#HDMI

That help section basically says that if you want to use external displays, you'll need to leave them unplugged until you are booted up and logged in, which is what you've experienced. This seems to be an issue with the Nvidia Optimus drivers. If I find anything else in regards to this, I'll update my answer.

As for your second issue, you could get the Nvidia Optimus drivers fully updated.

This gentleman appears to have a solid tutorial on how to get those installed and configured:

http://www.linuxveda.com/2015/07/16/how-to-install-drivers-for-nvidia-optimus-cards/

I'd post his instructions, but they are rather long.

That may be worth a shot, though I'm not sure what nvidia drivers you are currently using. You should also checkout **Bumblebee on Ubuntu** (I'd post a link but I'm currently limited to two links).

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is great information.  Thank you very much!